# An open set in $l^{\infty}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $X$ denote the set of all bounded real sequences, equipped with the norm $\| (x_n)\|_\infty:= \sup\{|x_1|,|x_2|,|x_3|,\ldots\}$; Let $X_{++}$ denote the set of all bounded positive real sequences (“sup” is supremum).
Is $X_{++}$ an open subset of $X$? Would anyone please tell me the answer to this question and provide suggestions or hints on how to prove it?

Comment: The space $X$ is also often called $\ell_\infty$.

Comment: Thank you, Martin Sleziak. You are right, the space X is indeed called ℓ∞. I used X instead of ℓ∞ just for easy typing.

Comment: It is not closed either. You can take $(X_{++}\ni)X_n:=(0,0,...,\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n+1},...) \rightarrow (0,0,0,...) \notin X_{++}$.

Answer (score 1):

The metric on X is induced by the norm, so that if $x = \{x_i\}$ and $y = \{y_i\}$ are elements of X, then $d(x,y) = \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |x_i - y_i|$.

Now I claim that $X_{++}$ is ***not*** an open set.

To show a set in a metric space is open, I have to show that for any element in that set, I can find an open ball around that element entirely contained in the set.

How could this go wrong? (This is the part that requires some thought. You have to pick the right sequence).

Did you want me to show you a sequence in $X_{++}$ such that every open ball around it contains points of $X \setminus X_{++}$? Or is this enough of a hint so far?

Another hint is that the sup norm is very strong. If two functions are close together in the sup norm, they are close together at every point of their domain. So if you have a sequence $\{x_i\} \in X$, an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $\{x_i\}$ consists of sequences that differ from $\{x_i\}$ by at most $\epsilon$ *at every coordinate*.

Let me know if you want more hints.

Comment: Thank you, user4894. You are right, I need to find a counterexample to prove X++ is not open. I think I can use the sequence {xi}=1/i (i=1,2,3,.....) to prove that any open ball around {xi} would include sequences that have nonpositive terms. Sorry for the late reply, there is a jet lag thing.